# Updating .txt file with year from subfolder

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am trying to learn how to update a .txt filename when os.walk switches from files in one directory to files in another directory. I am not sure about how to do this. I tried iterating through dirs and then files, but this was unsuccessful as the .pdf files would not display. Here is a full look at the code I am working on.

The directory looks like this [research] -> [2014] -> Article1.pdf, article2.pdf article3.pdf
[2015] -> Article4.pdf, article5.pdf article6.pdf
[2016] -> Article7.pdf, article8.pdf article9.pdf

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import os


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/bin/tesseract'

def image_ocr(image_path, output_txt_file_name, All_text):
    image_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
        image_path, lang='eng+ces', config='--psm 1')
    with open(output_txt_file_name, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(image_text)
    with open(All_text, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(image_text)


num = 0
year = 1973

year_being_recorded = 'txt_files/' + str(year) + '_article.txt'
cumulative_text = 'txt_files/cumulative.txt'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('articles'):
    for file_ in files:
        if file_.endswith('.pdf'):
            article_path = str(root) + '/' + str(file_)
            pages = convert_from_path(article_path, 500)
            for page in pages:
                name = 'jpegs/a_file_' + str(num) + '.jpeg'
                page.save(name, 'JPEG')
                image_ocr(name, year_being_recorded, cumulative_text)
                num = num + 1
```

Comment: Just to make sure, is this what you are trying to do: Extract the current folder name and append it to the filename?

Comment: Why not iterate over the contents of the research directory first, then the contents of each of its children?